A problem was found with the configuration of task ':composeApp:copyRoomSchemasToAndroidTestAssetsDebugAndroidTest' (type 'RoomSimpleCopyTask')
I got this error when I add room in CMP.

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':composeApp:copyRoomSchemasToAndroidTestAssetsDebugAndroidTest' (type 'RoomSimpleCopyTask').

In plugin 'androidx.room' type 'androidx.room.gradle.RoomSimpleCopyTask' property 'inputDirectory' specifies directory '/Users/../AndroidStudioProjects/BookApp/composeApp/schemas' which doesn't exist.
Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
Possible solutions:

Make sure the directory exists before the task is called.
Make sure that the task which produces the directory is declared as an input.



I make schemas folder manually but I got the error again

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':composeApp:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets'. > The value for task ':composeApp:copyRoomSchemasToAndroidTestAssetsDebugAndroidTest' property 'inputDirectory' is final and cannot be changed any further.

Android studio ladybug and MacBook M1 Pro

any solution to this issue?

PLEASE CHECK THE ANSWER PROVIDED BELOW.

I'm having the same problem right now. I believe the problem is the project's JDK version and what is installed on the computer.
Recently a colleague was using version 23.x and we had to change to 21.0.5 for the project. This solved the problem exactly, but it was when running and not when generating the APK/Bundle.

There are some sort of dependency issues in latest room version. Please use the below version in KMM/CMP projects to tackle the issue.
ksp = "2.0.20-1.0.24"
sqlite = "2.5.0-alpha12"
room = "2.7.0-alpha07"

